# kotlin + react Настройка конфигурации webpack

Tags: kotlin, webpack

Столкнулся с проблемой: не могу никак изменить конфигурацию webpack в базовом проекте kotlin + react.
Для примера - постоянно вылезает надпись типа:

```
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  Testing.js (335 KiB)
```

Чтобы ее убрать - согласно описанию необходимо выставить параметр в конфигурацию webpack

```
performance: {

hints:false

}
```

Однако я никак не могу найти место, откуда генерирются данные для webpack.config.js. В одном месте наткнулся на информациюю о том, что в корне проекта необходимо создать папку webpack.config.d. В нее необходимо поместить файл типа `test.conf`, после чего конфигурация подцепится. Такой способ не сработал.

Где может находиться генератор конфигурации? Как изменить базовый конфиг при работе с kotlin?

UPD.

после переименования конфигурационного файла в .js - данные начали записываться в файл webpack.config.js:

```
 module.exports = {
     performance: { 
        hints: 'false',
 },
};
```

Однако, без эффекта. в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Кавычки на результативность не влияют

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно удалось разобраться, но это не точно. Внутри файлы все export-значения связаны через отдельный выгружаемый модуль "config". Все новые данные должны добавляться в него. Соответственно, чтобы реализовать исключение напоминаний вместо конфигурации типа

```
module.exports = {
     performance: { 
        hints: 'false',
 },
};
```

необходимо делать следующее

```
config.performance = {
   hints: false,
 }
```

Пока проблем с таким решением не увидел...